# C++ MFC Bitmap displays incorrectly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bitmap, mfc, drawing

I am trying to get a background picture working in a MFC Dialog.

```
protected:
    CBitmap m_Background;
    CBrush m_BrushHold;
    CSize m_BitmapSize;

BOOL CNameDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    //[...]
    int i = m_Background.LoadBitmapW (30996);
    //int y = GetLastError();
    BITMAP bm;
    m_Background.GetBitmap (&bm);
    m_BitmapSize = CSize (bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
    Invalidate(1);
    //[...]
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

m_BitmapSize is WAY to low. (e.g. 33, 11 while the real size is 428, 368)

```
BOOL CLotteryDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDC dcMemory;
    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC (pDC);
    CBitmap* pOldbitmap = dcMemory.SelectObject (&m_Background);
    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect (&rcClient);
    const CSize &sbitmap = m_BitmapSize;
    pDC->BitBlt (0, 0, sbitmap.cx, sbitmap.cy, &dcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    dcMemory.SelectObject (pOldbitmap);
    return TRUE;
}
```

After painting it I will get either a small square in the top left corner or it displays

[image]

**How can I get it to display correctly ?**

Comment: Probably you have to check this magic number 30996. And I usually draw everything in OnPaint.

Comment: @Serhiy: Magic number ? That's my resource ID, it loads correctly, as `LoadBitmapW` returns 1. I have taken this resource ID of the compiled exe as my custom imported bitmap did not show the right ID. `GetLastError` was 1814. As already mentioned this should not be the problem as I fixed this... No matter if I draw it in paint or not, I have tried it, same result.

Comment: What the value of m_BitmapSize is?

Comment: @Serhiy: Currently it is `cx=15, cy=10`.

Comment: @Serhiy: I fixed it... I just took a new picture, saved it like the last one as .bmp file and now it works, strange... Thanks anyway.